# Year extraction of date and bar chart plot

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to draw a bar chart with products by year. There are 4 columns.
Column Date is in format = 2018-01-01...
and the other columns are numbers of the products.

There is a mistake in the transformation into a year column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('products.csv',sep=';', usecols=['Date','product1','product2','product3'],parse_dates=['Date'])
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df['Year']=df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

How can I do a new column 'year' with just 2018, 2019...
and put it into the bar chart?

Comment: So, once you set the axis to Date, the column doesn't exist anymore. Without seeing your data it's hard to tell. Could you share a few rows maybe? Most importantly, do you have multiple rows for each year? What is the bar chart supposed to aggregate for each year?

Comment: sorry you are right. row 0: Date=2018-01-01, products just numbers. Row 1: Date=2018-02-01....every row is a different day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since now the `Date` column has been turned into the `Index` of the dataframe, you can extract the "year" of this date directly from the index, assuming you have first checked that the index is indeed a `DatetimeIndex`.

```py
type(df.index) # Should return something like pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

# If it's a datetime index:
df['year'] = df.index.year
```

If `type(df.index)` is string or another type, you can first convert it to a `DatetimeIndex` and then extract the year, as such:

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).year
```